# Copy content of GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES texture to GL_TEXTURE_2D texture

Tags: opengl-es, texture2d

I have two textures, one is bound to GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES target, pixels in YUV format, the second one is empty and bound to GL_TEXTURE_2D target.

How can I can show content from first texture on second one?

Comment: External textures are specific to OpenGL ES; they don't exist on desktop GL. So you shouldn't tag the question with "opengl".

Comment: "*pixels in UAV format*" Do you mean "YUV"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to OpenGL ES 3.2, [EXT_copy_image](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_copy_image.txt), [OES_copy_image](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_copy_image.txt), or [APPLE_copy_texture_levels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/APPLE/APPLE_copy_texture_levels.txt), then you may be able to copy the image data with the appropriate copying command, defined by these specifications. There is no guarantee of being able to do this, since none of those specifications define the interaction with formats provided by OES_EGL_image_external.

So even if you have access to the command, it may not work for external images.

If none of that is available or if it doesn't work, then your only recourse is to bind the 2D texture to a framebuffer and render to it, reading the external texture as source data in your fragment shader.

That being said, the *whole point* of external images is to *avoid* such copies. You haven't stated what you're trying to do, so there's no advice I can really give. You may want to look into [OES_EGL_image](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image.txt) rather than external images.

Comment: Android system enables to preview from camera to opengl texture, and it must be GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES. I want to manipulate it, so I need it be a GL_TEXTURE_2D texture. I cannot rebind it, so I want to copy it to newly generated. Are there any other way?

Comment: The whole point of an external texture is that *you don't own it*. Someone "external" to you owns it; you are simply being given use of it. You aren't allowed to manipulate something that doesn't belong to you. You can read from it, but that's about it. If you want to get the data out of the image and poke at it, you must read from it.